In what ways are Carl Jung's "ego death" and biblical "dying to sin" similar and dissimilar?
I was reading a while back and wanted to piece together these two ideas in my head. But as I think more about it the cognitive dissonance only increases. Non-Christians can experience "ego death" (see this Wikipedia section), but "death to sin" happens after salvation, which means the two concepts don't fully overlap. But then, how can these two seemingly identical processes be justified to occur at different "stages of development" for different people? I hope this is clear enough of an inquiry.
A passage that comes to mind is Romans 6:11 (and a few other verses in the same chapter, as well):

"So you too consider yourselves dead to sin, but alive to God in Christ Jesus" - Romans 6:11 (NET)


I understand the quoted text and its meaning. But I cannot understand the need to compare a scriptural teaching with that of a philosopher who believed that Deity was merely an 'archetype of the collective subconscious'. Could you edit and explain the point of doing this, please ? Otherwise one doubts that the question is truly a matter of 'Christianity'.

@NigelJ To me this question represents an attempt by a deeply reflective person to understand how a Christian who needs "to die to self" experience this in practice.  This is within the domain of Christian psychology that tries to integrate the scientific study of the human mind with Biblical truths about humanity.  Aquinas did this by putting Aristotle to Christian service.  So unless one is committed philosophically to isolate theology in its own ivory tower (thus denies any commerce of the two disciplines) this question is relevant, even only to show the deficiencies of the Jungian view.

I would listen to the lectures of J.B. Peterson on this. He has a good ability to explain the Jungian understanding and combine it with Biblical understandings. (Lecture series on Genesis, Exodus, etc)

Thank you for the recommendation.

First, it is worth knowing what Jung's psychology was based upon, and then it might become clear whether there was anything 'Christian' about it. I quote from a scholarly article on this:

"Carl Jung was fixated on the symbolic parallels between external
'things' and internal mind/consciousness. He understood himself not as
a psychologist, but as a psychological sorcerer. His occult beliefs
concerned a supposed unity of good and evil in the human psyche and in
God. His occult practices were what New Age people today would
recognise as "channeling". He was a pantheist. He taught that we have
to accept evil as the partner of good. That is his idea of
"integrating" evil with good.
He admitted that his "dreams and visions" formed "the prima material
of [his] scientific work." He was channeling, making contact with
spirit guides. His belief in synchronicity meant that he corresponded
interior or mental things and events with exterior or physical things
or events. This led him to believe that the world has no reality apart
from the mind that experiences it. This enabled him to dismiss the
question whether his personal myth is true. He believed it made no
difference whether his gurus or guides were real spirits or just
fantasies. But when he described the way they affected him, he used
adjectives like "demonic" and "diabolical".
The frankest of his confessions are in his "Psychology and Religion :
West and East". Also in his "Memories, Dreams, Reflections". He
spoke of entities called Elijah, Salome and Philemon (who was a pagan
and brought with him an Egypto-Hellenistic atmosphere with a Gnostic
coloration.)" Extracted from an article by Prof. J Budziszewski in
"Christian Research Journal" Spring 2000, pages 30-33 http://www.equip.org

Many people who are unaware of the extent to which Jungian beliefs have informed today's atheism and other worldviews might be surprised to discover the extent to which popular culture has imbibed many Jungian ideas; Star Wars ('the Force'), Star Trek (one early episode depicting the good force as listless, frail and irresolute), The Dark Crystal (a children's film).
Now we may be better enabled to respond to comparing Jung's 'ego death' with the biblical concept of "death to sin". My point will come from Paul's words in 1 Timothy 1:15 - "Christ Jesus came into the world to save sinners: of whom I am chief".
Paul's use of present tense (as opposed to saying 'of whom I was chief') accords with Christian belief that becoming a Christian does not stop you from continuing to sin, and that although God does not hold your past sins against you, that does not erase the fact that you committed them. Anyone who knows what Paul did when known as Saul of Tarsus will understand his meaning and his immeasurable regret at those sins. Context shows he was using himself as an example of the extent of Christ's amazing saving power. But Jung's esoteric understanding is utterly at odds with the reality of actual sin committed by people, and how God deals with what they truly did, via a truly historic event witnessed by many on a dark hillside called Golgotha, nearly 2,000 years ago, outside of Jerusalem.
The answer submitted is that there is nothing similar whatsoever between Jung's 'ego death', and Christian (i.e. biblical) 'dying to sin.'

"nothing similar" Up-voted +1.

A startling number of folks are willing to entertain that, perhaps, only their mind exists and all else is illusion. This Jungian poison  is couched as 'logical'. +1
